# I cannot get into my Ubuntu hard drive, because I messed my grub up - I have important documents on the drive

Tags: 16.04

Using Ubuntu 16.04.1 Desktop, I accidentally installed something that screwed with my graphics, so I went into rescue mode with a SERVER usb install stick, not a desktop one, and when I went to 'shell' , I was able to look at all my stuff. went into my home dir and saw my files, I was panicing and I went to 'rewrite grub' and i chose /dev/sda, told me 'failed' at 50% - then, i did /dev/sda1 - it didn't tell me 'grub write successful' but now, I cannot even SEE the drive on any computer's boot menu. If you have the knowledge, please assist.

edited-
making a little progress...I've found my files via boot repair, but, when I copy and pasted the command, it didn't want to install grub2. wouldn't let me continue so I clicked out of it, now I'm waiting on desktop 16.04.2 to download, and gonna try that live cd option.

Comment: boot up a live CD in Legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

use

## df

and

## find /put your dir

to configure your gui

sudo apt-get remove gui

dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gui

sudo apt-get install xorg

startx

Comment: I appreciate you coming in and trying to assist me. I am in grub rescue mode, at this point, I've used boot-repair via usb to  attempt to fix the system. I was able to view the files that are important, but did not have permission to move them. I then inadvertently wiped grub, now not even that will work, and it's in rescue mode. ls gives me hd0, msdos5

Comment: @Strong, if you can see the files try coping them. you may need root privilege to do it

Answer (score 0):

You nees to check if you are a normal user or superuser

if you on gurb mode chose root option to be able to write command.

use:

$whoami

If it says root then you are.
If it says otherwise;
Then you need to add this username to superusers
file on /etc/sudoers.d

$cd /etc/sudoers.d
adduser (username)

insert password

$login
add new the username and password you created above

btw you can install the missing packeges from server 
just plug ethernat cable it will automatic connect to network

reinstall gui by typing

$sudo apt-get update

$sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

$reboot